# where can I find out more on a type of javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript, iife

What is this type of syntax called in javascript?

```
 (function(){})()
```

and this

```
  !function(){}()
```

I'd like to do a search to learn about them but I don't know what I'm searching for.

Also if anyone can provide  link to a useful recourse that would be great.

Comment: Google for IIFE and SIFE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the syntax for IIFE (Immediately Invoked Functions in Javascript).

This is a great article that should clear all your doubts:

http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/